When using moveit-setup-assist to configure the motion planning group in ros2, how is the 6-DOF dexterous hand configured?
<group name="head">
    <chain base_link="link-Body" tip_link="link-H1"/>
</group>
<group name="body">
    <chain base_link="base_link" tip_link="link-Body"/>
</group>
<group name="left_arm">
    <chain base_link="link-L0" tip_link="link-L7"/>
</group>
<group name="right_arm">
    <chain base_link="link-R0" tip_link="link-R7"/>
</group>
<group name="gripper">
    <chain base_link="hand_e_link" tip_link="hande_left_finger"/>
</group>
<group name="hand_J1">
    <joint name="hand_joint1"/>
</group>
<group name="hand_J2">
    <joint name="hand_joint2"/>
</group>
<group name="hand_J3">
    <joint name="hand_joint3"/>
</group>
<group name="hand_J4">
    <joint name="hand_joint4"/>
</group>
<group name="hand_J5">
    <joint name="hand_joint5"/>
</group>
<group name="hand_J6">
    <joint name="hand_joint6"/>
</group>

Can I configure 6 active joints into one planning group? Currently I configure 6 joints into separate planning groups。

here is the rviz sence， the hand is as showed
